# Running python script that contains "behave" command in java

Tags: java, python, selenium, python-behave

**I am trying to run python script inside a java code by creating Process with Runtime**

This is the contents of my java code:

```
String pythonPath = "/usr/local/bin/python3";
String runTestPath = "/Users/tuko/Documents/eclipse-workspace/WebLang_v2/runTests.py";

String[] cmd = new String[] {pythonPath, runTestPath};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

This is the contents of my python script:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output("behave",shell=True) 
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This is the output:

> Command 'behave' returned non-zero exit status 127.

Java doesn't recognize "behave" command. How to make this command recognizable by java

Comment: Why can't you just run `behave` directly from java?

Comment: Huh, didn't know Behave was available for Java.  Here's the link I found: https://jbehave.org/